# Logback RollingFileAppender: Don't lock logfile / Don't create empty logfile

Tags: java, log4j, logback

i've 2 Logfiles that i write with the Logback RollingFileAppender.

The first appender logs everything to file and roll it dailys. (daily log file)
The second appender logs only errors to a file and roll it every second. (logfile for every exception)

I've two problems with this appenders:

The first problem is that the daily log file is locking during the app is started. So i'm unable to rename / delete the logfile during the app is started. (problem appears to the daily appender)

The second problem is that an empty logfile is generated for every app start. (problem appears to the exception appender)

Is it possible two solve these two problems?

Here are the two appenders:

```
<!-- LOGFILE Ausgabe Appender -->
<appender name="LOGFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- logfile taeglich wechseln -->
        <fileNamePattern>C:/ProgramData/MyApp/Logs/MyApp_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- max 45 files behalten -->
        <maxHistory>45</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Exception Ausgabe Appender - Jeder ERROR wird in ein eigenes File geschrieben -->
<appender name="EXCEPTIONFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <!-- Nur ERROR Level Eintraege selektieren -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <!-- ERROR Logging -->
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- logfile sekuendlich wechseln -->
        <fileNamePattern>C:/ProgramData/MyApp/Logs/MyApp_Exception_%d{yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH-mm-ss}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <!-- max 50 files behalten, ist aber nur fallback die die dateien nach dem versenden sowieso geloescht werden -->
        <maxHistory>50</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS};%-5level;%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Thx.